# VS-Code Carriage Return not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

The issue I have is with the carriage return; in between angle brackets html/JSX elements in a `.jsx` or `.js` file. Prior to making some changes in the `json` settings, my carriage return would function normally i.e. if I hit the carriage return in between the angle brackets in an html element, the end result would be one element spread across three lines with the cursor on the empty middle line.

If my cursor is in between the angle brackets here:

`<section className="heading"></section>`

Then pressing the return key should result in this:

```
<section className="heading">
 
</section>
```

Instead when I press return this is what I get:

```
<section className="heading">
  </section>
```

I made a quick 15 second video doing an A / B comparison between how it used to be and how it is now. I know, pictures of text are the worst, but maybe there's something there that I'm missing https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTKON.jpg

I don't know what I changed that made this happen. I've been messing with the prettier settings to no avail. Here's my repo with the Vs Code settings:
https://github.com/Pashovski/settings/blob/main/settings.json

Comment: works fine for me using the your settings.json

Comment: Have you installed any extension recently?

Comment: @md2perpe I did install a couple of extensions, and have now uninstalled them. I even tried a clean install of VS Code on a new machine, and I get the same behavior. I noticed it works properly on an html file, but not a js or jsx file.